# Loading distinct rows from flatfile(listfile) to Target using informatica cloud

Tags: postgresql, informatica, informatica-cloud, iics-di

I have a flatfiles as a source I'm loading 4files at a time using indirect load, here I want to load only distinct rows, if a record present in file1, the same record may contain in file2.  So I need to insert only 1 record, the record should ignore, I tried sorter transformation distinct option, but it's not worked as I'm fetching the filename to the target.  As filename is differs sorter thinks it's a distinct values.

Please help me with solution how to load only distinct records.

Answer (score 1):

After sorting, utilizing the aggregator transformation with a group by on all columns except "Filename" will help extract distinct records using the maximum file name.

source date :
id  name    file_name
101 anvesh  files_1
102 sai krishna files_1
103 naren   files_1
101 anvesh  files_2
104 ankitha files_2
105 lakshmi files_2
101 anvesh  files_3
102 sai krishna files_3
107 rajesh  files_3

Target data: after aggregate
id  name    file_name
101 anvesh  files_3
102 sai krishna files_3
103 naren   files_1
104 ankitha files_2
105 lakshmi files_2
107 rajesh  files_3